# Commands and Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am taking input in the form of a command `Command arg args` and then getting the command name from a `Hashtable` and using a variable from a returned `String[]` and using reflection to call a method.
But I'm getting an which error I'll get to.

Code:
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Boot.boot();

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] command = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    String[] commandListOutput = Boot.command.commands.get(command[0]);
    int numbOfArgs = commandListOutput.length - 1;
    Object[][] argsArray = new String[1][numbOfArgs];
    Class<?>[] argsArrayClasses = new Class<?>[]{Object[].class};

    for(int i = 0; i > numbOfArgs; i++){
        if(i != 0){
            argsArray[0][i] = command[i];
        }
    }



    invokeMethod(commandListOutput[numbOfArgs], "command", argsArrayClasses, argsArray[0]);
    scanner.close();
}
```

Input:

```
newcommand foo bar
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.cjcl.Main.invokeMethod(Main.java:39)
at com.cjcl.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

invokeMethod:

```
public static void invokeMethod(String className, String methodName,
        Class<?>[] paramTypes, Object[] params) {
    try {

        Class<?> commandclass = Class.forName(className);
        Method method = commandclass.getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        method.invoke(method, params);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
            | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException
            | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Method (I havent written it yet its for debug):

```
public static void command(Object[] foo){
    System.out.println("invoked");
}
```

I've tried everything and this is my final code.

Thanks curlip

Comment: What is `invokeMethod`? And what is the method you want to invoke? What parameters does it have?

Comment: invokeMethod(); is the method for reflection.
The method is called command and it has 1 Object[] as a parameter.

Comment: Show us the code. Show us how you call `invoke`.

Comment: You seem to be invoking a method on a `Method` instance. Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: Invoke the method related to the input command

Comment: The first argument to `Method#invoke` should be the object to invoke the method on. Currently, you're passing your `Method` object as the object to invoke the method on.

Comment: The method is static so their is no need to have an object to invoke it on.

Comment: In that case, pass `null`. It's otherwise unclear what you are doing. As for the error, we still need to see the method you are invoking. Print it out to confirm.

Comment: Which method the one I am Invoking

Comment: Yes, print out `method`.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your for loop in which you are populating argsArray has `i > numbOfArgs` instead of `i < numbOfArgs`, so your array is still empty when you pass it to invokeMethod.

Comment: THank you but this has not resolved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing a array with X amount of objects not an array containing an object array. Changing the for condition helped to.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Boot.boot();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] command = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    String[] commandListOutput = Boot.command.commands.get(command[0]);
    int numbOfArgs = commandListOutput.length - 1;
    Object[][] argsArray = new String[1][numbOfArgs];
    Class<?>[] argsArrayClasses = new Class<?>[]{Object[].class};

    int i = 0;
    for(Object obj : argsArray){
        i++;
        if(i != 0){
            argsArray[0][i] = command[i];
        }
    }



    invokeMethod(null, commandListOutput[numbOfArgs], "command", argsArrayClasses, argsArray);
    scanner.close();
}
```